# How to use an ObservedObject as the selection in a Picker along with default selection in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker

I'm looking to use an Observed Object class as the selection for a Picker I am trying to implement.  The Picker options are populated from an array of the same class objects.  Everything works fine until I try and set a default selection to the Picker based on previously saved data.  When I set the selection to the name property, the default selection gets set correctly, but then I'm not able to change the Picker selection. I'm able to click into the list of options, and the default is selected correctly, but clicking on any other option just returns to the form and the selection isn't changed.

I'm relatively new to Swift and SwiftUI, so it's likely there is just something I'm not understanding correctly, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the class and struct for the objects I'm using:

```
struct DisciplineData: Codable, Hashable {
    var _id:String = ""
    var name:String = ""
    var isDefault:Bool = false
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(_id)
    }
}

class DisciplineDataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data:DisciplineData = DisciplineData()
    var dataPresent:Bool {
        data.name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty ? false : true
    }
    
    func setDisciplineDataProperties(newData: DisciplineData) {
        self.data = newData
    }
    
    func getPropertiesAsDisciplineData() -> DisciplineData {
        let data:DisciplineData = DisciplineData()
        
        return data
    }
}
```

Here is the version of the Picker that works, but the default selection doesn't appear:

```
private struct DisciplineSectionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var discipline:DisciplineDataModel
    var disciplines: [DisciplineData] = []
    @Binding var disabled:Bool
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text("Discipline")) {
            Picker("Discipline:", selection: $discipline.data) {
                ForEach(disciplines, id:\.self) { discipline in
                    Text(discipline.name)
                }
            }
            .disabled(disabled)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the version of the Picker where the default selection appears, but

```
private struct DisciplineSectionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var discipline:DisciplineDataModel
    var disciplines: [DisciplineData] = []
    @Binding var disabled:Bool
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text("Discipline")) {
            Picker("Discipline:", selection: $discipline.data.name) {
                ForEach(disciplines, id:\.self.name) { discipline in
                    Text(discipline.name)
                }
            }
            .disabled(disabled)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear how do you store/restore default data of DisciplineDataModel. It should be one of the picked array. I thing the issues is in that you create new DisciplineData() in model. The variant with selection name is not the way.

Comment: Thank you!  You were 100% correct in that DisciplineData was getting overwritten.  I was making an API call to load the stored data in .onAppear, so every time a Picker selection was made, it would revert back to the default selection because the API call would be made again.  I was not aware that Pickers functioned this way, but it makes sense.  Thanks for putting me on the right path!